# Authentication using Secure LDAP (ie LDAPS) in C#

Tags: c#, ldap

I am able to validate a user against Active Directory using following code and it works fine:

```
bool authentic = false;
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
// validate the credentials against domain
authentic = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
```

However the username and password are being sent to network in plain text. I was told to use `ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer` with `ValidateCredentials` but it throws exception

> *The server cannot handle directory requests.*

Can anyone please help me with this so that I can authenticate with LDAP server in a secure way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I need to know this too. I think (but haven't tested) that ContextOptions.Negotiate will use SSL. You **may** need to force the port to 636 e.g.

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain + ":636", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

or

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain + ":636", ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing);
```

EDIT
I have this working now (as above). The only problem I had was I was trying to connect with IP address. This didn't work but I didn't know why until I looked in windows **Event Viewer** (on client) and there were errors about the certificate. When I changed to servername that matched the certificate, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP clients should always use SSL or a non-secure connection promoted to a secure connection with the StartTLS extended operation - modern, professional-quality servers have the capability to reject operations on non-secure connections, though legacy servers often lack this feature. LDAP is *encoded*, not *encrypted*, for transmission.

Check with the directory server administrator to ensure that SSL (or StartTLS) is supported by the server, check that the certificates involved are valid. Consider using `openssl s_client -connect host:port` to validate the connection.